# How to do Promise.promisfyAll(fs) without globally modifying fs (when writing a library)?

Tags: javascript, bluebird

AFAICT, if I'm writing a library and I use `Promise.promisifyAll(fs);`, this modifies the `fs` module in place (rather than returning a modified copy). So if someone imports my library, this has the side effect of modifying `fs` for them too.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: The modified object just has new properties added to it (the "xxxAsync" methods).  The prior existing properties are not changed at all.  It is 100% compatible with the object that existed before.  Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: I agree it's unlikely to cause problems, but I would feel much more comfortable with an alternative that gives me a new object instead of adding methods to a built-in module that everyone uses. Importing my library shouldn't cause side effects, even if those side effects are probably harmless.

Comment: Also, it's undocumented what happens if another module also loads bluebird and calls `promisifyAll(fs)` after my library has done it already. Does it overwrite the methods again or just leave them? What if we are using different bluebird versions with slightly different promisifyAll behaviours? Things could go wrong.

Comment: FYI, per a test I did, calling `promisifyAll()` on an object that is already promisified does not replace the previously promisified methods - it just leaves the prior ones in place.  It turns out each promisified method has an `__isPromisified__: true` property which Bluebird looks at to see that its work has already been done for that method.

Comment: You could always just promisify() the individual functions you happen to be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wrapper object for the global that you don't want to alter:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(function(orig) {
    var myFs = {};
    for (var m in orig)
        myFs[m] = orig[m]; // .bind(orig); is probably unnecessary
    return myFs;
}(require('fs')));
```

Comment: (disclaimer: untested. I assume node `fs` does expose all methods as enumerable, and there's nothing else)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make a generic copy of the original `fs` object and then just call `Promise.promisifyAll()` on the copy?  As you have it you're reimplementing some of the logic that `promisifyAll()` already contains in deciding which methods to operate on

Comment: @jfriend00: Yeah, that's probably a better idea. I initially feared that `fs` methods might not work on a foreign `this` object, but that's unlikely. Edited my answer.